# count to calculate records after conditions are met

Tags: php

I have this foreach to display individual lessons. However, as you can see in the code below, I am omitting some of the records. Additionally, through use of `$found` I'm minimising messages to just one message.

```
$found = false;

foreach($lessons as $lesson)
{
    if(Auth::LoggedIn())
    {
       if(Auth::$userinfo->rank == 'Student')
       {
           if($lesson->aircraft == 'C172')
           {
                $found = true;
                break;
           }
           if($lesson->theory == '1')
           {
                $found = true;
                break;
           }
       }

     /* Actual foreach data here, a table row displaying a result */
}
if($found)
{
    echo '<div class="msg-yellow"><strong>A selection of lessons could not be displayed, because you have to complete other lessons first.</strong></div><br/>';
}
```

I was wondering how I can do a vice-versa solution to another message. Basically, I have this message which counts all of the records found. I'd like for the message to disappear, if there is no records displayed, plus I'm finding that whenever the records are hidden, the below solution will still count them.

Say, there are 50 records in the database, and `$if(lesson->aircraft == 'C172'` would leave out six records. It should display as 44, and not 50, like it does. I suppose this is because the `count` I have is outside the foreach, above it, so it counts all the records before the conditions.

`<div class="msg-blue"><strong>Your search criteria returned <?php echo count($lessons); ?> lessons available for booking.</strong>`

How can I get the above to display only when the if conditions are met, and for the message to dissapear if there are no records displayed?

Comment: Sounds to me like what you want to do (also I’m not sure I understood you fully) should rather be done in the database query already – whereas now you seem to be loading all records, and then do some simple filtering script-side.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of hidden results, and subtract them from the total results to get the number of actually displayed results. To hide the message when no results are displayed, just check if this difference is higer then 0. To keep the order the table has to be cached in a variable (`$table` in this example) until the number of search results has been displayed.

```
$hidden_count = 0;
$table = "";
foreach($lessons as $key => $lesson)
{
    if(Auth::LoggedIn())
    {
       if(Auth::$userinfo->rank == 'Student')
       {
           if($lesson->aircraft == 'C172')
           {
                $hidden_count += 1;
                break;
           }
           if($lesson->theory == '1')
           {
                $hidden_count += 1;
                break;
           }
       }

     /* Actual foreach data here, a table row displaying a result, not echoed but appended to $table */
}
$count_after = count($lessons) - $hidden_count;

echo '<div class="msg-blue"><strong>Your search criteria returned $count_after flights available.</strong>';
echo $table;

$count_diff = $count_before - $count_after;
if($hidden_count > 0 && $count_after > 0)
{
    echo '<div class="msg-yellow"><strong>$count_diff lessons could not be displayed, because you have to complete other lessons first.</strong></div><br/>';
}
```

Comment: It might not be a good idea to actually remove elements from $lessons because it might introduce new bugs if $lessons is being used anywhere down the code

Comment: You're right, although I doubt that it will be used later, as this code just displays a search result. However, I'm currently editing my answer to get rid of unset(), thanks for your comment. @Abhay

Answer (score 0):

it is incorrect to use count($lessons) for displaying the count since $lessons may contain records that you do not want to display. Instead, you should create another counter variable (say $countLesson); set it to 0 in the top and increment it within your foreach when $found=false. This counter variable will give you the right count.

For not displaying the message if there are no records, you may use:

```
if ($countLesson > 0) {
    // display message
}
```

Hope it helps!